# Can iPhone app using custom framework with Mach-O object be rejected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I has made a custom framework by referencing the following guide.

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/05/creating-universal-framework-to-iphone-ios/

I found that the output library file is not ar library but Mach-O object.

```
(for architecture armv7):   Mach-O object arm
(for architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)):    Mach-O object arm
(for architecture i386):    Mach-O object i386
```

Fortunately, this framework absolutely be merged into the final product who uses it. But, I am not sure that it can pass the Apple's examination.

Is it right to pass the examination for registering to App Store?

**UPDATE:**
Finally, I found the way to make a ar library by referencing that site, http://code.google.com/p/ios-static-framework/.
But, I don't want to use that static framework. Because I want to hide several symbols I used in the framework for avoiding symbol duplication.

Comment: Well, all your source files eventually pass through the state if being an object file... I don't see why/how that would get to rejection, since it is done with all the source code of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is native and objective-c you shouldn't have any problems.  Though I did find this:

http://blog.cascadesoft.net/2010/09/10/new-app-store-rules-and-the-objective-c-versus-3rd-party-framework-question-for-iphone-apps/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :-) Do you know why that type of framework I asked is used less than archive type(ar) of static framework?

Comment: "And Objective-C" - it needn't be Objective-C.